# How to solve too many re-renders error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator, react-functional-component

I am trying to make a switch in react which renders a particular icon if a state is false and another one if the state is true...I am trying to change the state if a button is clicked..But I am getting this error:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to
> prevent an infinite loop.

this is the javascript of the error giving component:

```
const [wantsPassword, setWantsPassword] = useState(false)
```

and this is the JSX:

```
   <IconButton onClick={setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}  >
      {wantsPassword?<VisibilityOffIcon/>:<VisibilityIcon />}
    </IconButton>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you call the set function *on render*, rather than on click. You need to make `onClick` a function, not a function invocation:

```
   <IconButton onClick={() => setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function in `onClick` on every render `<IconButton onClick={setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}  >`

Change it to:

```
<IconButton onClick={() => setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't execute the function inside the onClick. Instead do like below:-

```
<IconButton onClick={() => setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the arrow function like this:

```
<IconButton onClick={() => setWantsPassword(!wantsPassword)}  >
```